# Connecting to Azure Blob Storage from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the [CloudBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.getblobreferencefromserverasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobClient_GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync_System_Uri_) c# class in my v2 function app to read data from a file stored on Azure Blob Storage. When running locally my code is able to pull back the data, however when the code is deployed with the same connection string and my code call `GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync`, I get the following error:

`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

I took the connection string from Storage Account > Access Keys > Connection String for Key1, which has the following format:

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<AccountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

I have tried giving the App Service Account Owner access to the storage account and tried using shared access signatures, but nothing has worked so far. Are there certain permissions that need to be applied on either the Function App or Storage Account end in order to get this functionality working?

Below is a snippet of the code:

```cs
var storageConnectionString = blobConfig.ConnectionString;
if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out var storageAccount))
{
    try
    {
        // Create the CloudBlobClient that represents the Blob storage endpoint for the storage account.
        var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var uri = new Uri(cloudBlobClient.BaseUri, $"/{containerName}{path}");

        // get the blob object and download to file
        // ---- THROWS ON NEXT LINE ----
        var blobRef = await cloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(uri); 

        var tempFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        await blobRef.DownloadToFileAsync(tempFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Truncate);

        return tempFilePath;
    }
    catch (StorageException ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex, "Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I should mention that the deployed version of this function is running on an Azure Dev/Test subscription. Not sure if that is at play here. I am going to try to deploy to a non-Dev subscription and see if it resolves anything.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is being properly loaded? Where is the blobConfig loaded from/is blobConfig.ConnectionString set properly?

Comment: Please check that your connection string is properly configured (App Settings?) and loaded in your function in Azure.

Comment: @ikkentim - It is being loaded from the function's app settings. I was able to check that it was correct by base64 encoding it and logging it to application insights.

Comment: Is there a slash missing in your string `$"/{containerName}{path}` between containername and path? Which may end up in a different container name (with different access permissions?)

Comment: @SebastianAchatz - the path has a preceding "/". The output of the uri is well formed and does point to an existing blob

Comment: Has your Azure Blob Storage some vnet or https connection restrictions?

Comment: The settings in Firewalls and virtual networks are set to "All Networks", not sure how to check https connection restrictions

Comment: There is a setting in the Azure Portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer

Comment: @SebastianAchatz - Ahh I see, yes that is enabled

Comment: Is that set in your connection string `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https`?

Comment: Yeah the connection string was using https. I did some testing and it looks like the issue was the type of Azure subscription. Looked for documentation on the deficiencies between those two types of subscriptions but could not find anything. Wish MS would make their error messages a bit more useful....Probably too much to expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some testing, it looks like this is an issue isolated to Dev/Test subscriptions. A bit frustrating that I had to bang my head against the wall for a day to figure this out, but I guess that is the name of the game.

Hopefully this can help someone else running up against this issue.

Comment: Could you explain how you figured that out cause I believe this to be my issue as well.

Comment: @G3tinmybelly a little late for a response - my apologies. We wound up upgrading the subscription from a Dev/Test to full Enterprise version and magically the issue went away. I haven't gone back and revisited recently so not sure if it is still an issue or not